# Most appropriate way to pass argument in Unix Terminal

Tags: unix, grep, find, xargs

I'm trying to find some files with given string in directory with lots of subdirectories and files within it,

I know regex/glob expression to match for target files and names of middle directories from other command. Example directory listing command output:

```
1234
5321
4546
2456
```

I'm trying to do it using find and grep, but I can't pass properly directory names to find using xargs. Final command is:

```
commandOutputDirs | xargs -d\n find /path/to/search/*/{} -type f -name "*fileName*"
```

But I get following error =  `find: paths must precede expression: 1234`

When I try to use echo instead of find the

> /path/to/search/*/{}

evaluates to

> /path/to/search/path 1234

Do I need to pass those arguments some other way to achieve same effect?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are actually trying to do! Are you looking for files which contain a string within their contents? Or are you looking for files whose names contain a given string? Or are you looking for files whose path contains a given string? And what do you want to do with those files when you find them?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I need to find out if given string exists in some of directories in files with specific name (I'm looking for error in log files). I can get the names of subdirectories in which to look for files from **commandOutputDirs**. I also know the name of files in which string to find later reside. I want to get the list of files and then grep them to look for that string.

Comment: Like this? `find   /tmp  /etc/  /some/Where/Else -type f ...`

Comment: More like this: find /path/to/hugeDir/subDir1 /path/to/hugeDir/subDir2 ... /path/to/hugeDir/subDirN -type f ...

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a file pattern.txt that contains

```
usr
etc
var
```

you could do like this :

```
 while read line; do find /path/$line -type f -name "*filename*  < pattern.txt
```

If it a command-line output do as the following :

```
commandLineOutput | while read line; do find /path/$line -type f -name "*filename*
```